# Why framelayout's gravity doesn't work here?

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:id="@+id/dog"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/dog"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cat"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/cat"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rabbit"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/rabbit"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/horse"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/horse"></ImageView>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FF00"></TabWidget>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

In the `<FrameLayout>` I set the `gravity="center"`. So, `<ImageView>`s should be appear on the center of `<FrameLayout>`.

But, when I run this code `<ImageView>`s are on the left|top of the `<FrameLayout>`. Why it doesn't work?

But, when I set `<ImageView>`'s `layout_gravity="center"` it works.

I know the difference between `layout_gravity` and `gravity`, but in this example, `<FrameLayout>`'s `gravity="center"` has to work. But, I don't know why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply just because you **can't** use `android:gravity` in FrameLayout. To align child's position inside FrameLayout, you need to set LayoutParams at child view with `android:layout_gravity`. That's the right way.

By the way, just FYI, `android:gravity` works in LinearLayout.